# How can I increase the output current while using LLC topology ? (see details)

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, charger

I am using a DC-DC LLC topology for my power supply. My input voltage is 400V DC (after PFC boosting.) I need 60VDC 20A, but I only get 12A.

I have tried:

1. My switching frequency is at the resonance.
2. I have tried several combination of Lr and Cr so that by varying the switching frequency I can achieve current. It did not help much.
3. Changed the DC DC transformer turns ratio.

Information about the schematic:

I am using a microcontroller to control the drive of the MOSFET. At resonant frequency I am getting the highest power (60V x 12A ) but it is not enough.

I am sensing the output voltage and output current using an ADC.
If my current/voltage exceeds the limit I control the switching frequency.

Please suggest what else I can try or what improvements in this I can make.

[image]

Comment: Please add your schematic diagram.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an easy question to answer without a schematic. Besides, is this an off the shelf PSU or did you make this on your own? Or are you trying to modify an off the shelf PSU? If the PSU is designed for 60V 12A, simply modifying the magnetics is not enough. You have to replace all semiconductors for the rated current, recalculate value for the filter components, increase the current handling capabilities of the PCB traces (you would have to scrape off the solder mask and add a thick layer of solder to the copper traces), upgrade the heatsinks, etc

Comment: @Andyaka i have attached the schematic kindly do the needful.

Comment: @PrathikPrashanth i have added the schematic.

Comment: The transformer has internal LR (created by gap between primary and secondary winding ). earlier i was using a separate Lr, but it also didn't surve the purpose.

Comment: It looks like a portion of this schematic has been cut. Also, did you design this circuit?

Comment: @PrathikPrashanth Yes the portion of the Schematic is cut, since the other part included, PFC section, Microntroller, LEDs FAN etc that was not neccesary. yes i have designed the circuit.

Comment: You’ve ‘designed’ this circuit but you can’t debug it? What happens if you draw more than 12A? How much energy are you putting in vs what you are getting out? Find the weak link.

Comment: @Kartman i can draw 20A, even 22A but i have to compromise with the voltage drop. My design gives 94% efficiency. The design needs to be 1.2KW but it is delivering only 840W.

Comment: See, this is what I dont understand. You have designed a 60V 12A LLC resonant mode PSU with active PFC and all that, but you cant figure out how to upgrade it to a 60V 20A PSU? It just doesn't add up. Besides, this circuit is so advanced that you can't really get any help from us. To help you out, someone would have to spend a few hours simulating your circuit to understand it and then poke around the prototype to see if anything is wrong. But I'll tell you what, if you really made this circuit on your own, then you can upgrade it on your own.